# Facebook-approved way to increase conversion from app requests?

Tags: facebook, notifications, apprequests

I have a question about increasing visibility of Facebook app notifications.

As far as I can tell, there are only 2 places where Facebook app requests appear for users who don't click the "Apps & Games" section - in the top right section (https://skitch.com/nicksoman/8172w/facebook) or in the jewel (https://skitch.com/nicksoman/81737/2-facebook) - I believe the wording is a bit different on this one if recipients haven't used the app, as it references an invite rather than a request.

As other have noted, neither of these channels provides any context around the request.  In the past I've seen context for apps like BranchOut and FarmVille, but I can't replicate this behavior by sending invites from these apps now (can anyone)?

Has anyone found a Facebook-approved way to either provide more context around these app requests or make them more visible?

I'm familiar with the history of Facebook tweaking channels due to abusive apps - just want to make sure I'm current on best practices today.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to users who haven't authorized your app or users who did?

Basically, facebook calls this [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) and you have a few options, again, depending on if the user is already using your app or not.

If the user is using your app, you have the bookmarks bar which can be used by issuing a App-generated requests.

If the user isn't using your app then a friend of his that is using your app can send him a User-generated request.

You can and should encourage your users to publish your app stories [to their friends' feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and/or to [send them to friends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/).

There's that "Automatic Channels" which is discussed in the first link in this answer.

More options are to use the [Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) in your website, and to have a [mobile version](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) of your app.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan.  I'm sorry I wasn't clear - I'm aware of the other options (e.g. posting to feeds), but I'm specifically interested in increasing visibility of the app requests option.  Good point on the bookmarks bar (an aggregate count of requests for the app shows up for users of the app there as well).  Do you know of any other way to make app requests more visible?

Comment: The apprequests have their own way of being displayed, there's nothing you can do to change/control that. The only thing that you can do is to use as much "Social Channels" to get to more users.